# Why am I getting "Prelude.read : no parse" on reading a string from stdin

Tags: haskell, monads

I'm running into an issue with printing results from my `forM_` loop.  I'm expecting the last `putStrLn` function to output the result.  For those that want the link to the problem - https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/sherlock-and-anagrams

```
--Returns a sublist of xs from 'from' to 'to'
slice from to xs = take (to - from + 1) (drop from xs)

--Checks if all elements in list are identical
allTheSame xs = and $ zipWith (==) xs (tail xs)

--Handles validating an anagram
checkForTwoOccurences :: [Char] -> [[Char]] -> Bool
checkForTwoOccurences occ arr
    | allTheSame occ == True = False 
    | reverse occ == occ = False
    | (occ `elemIndex` arr /= Nothing) = True
    | otherwise = False

--Returns the count of anagrams that are substrings of s - n is length of s
findAnagrams s n = 
    let res = concat $ [ tail $ inits $ slice x (n-1) s | x <- [0..n-1] ]
    in foldl (\acc x -> if (checkForTwoOccurences (reverse x) res) then (succ acc) else acc) 0 res


main :: IO ()
main = do 

    t_temp <- getLine
    let t = read t_temp :: Int

    forM_ [1..t] $ \a0  -> do
        s_temp <- getLine
        let s = read s_temp :: String
        putStrLn $ show $ findAnagrams s $ length s
```

Comment: `read s_temp :: String` means that `s_temp` needs to be a string with the value `"\"something\""` for it to parse correctly.  The string `"something"` is not equivalent.  I think you could just skip the `read` and pass the result of `getLine` directly through to `findAnagrams` and `length`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comment states, you don't need to "read" your string -- its already a string!

So change

```
    s_temp <- getLine
    let s = read s_temp :: String
    putStrLn $ show $ findAnagrams s $ length s
```

to

```
    s <- getLine
    putStrLn $ show $ findAnagrams s $ length s
```

And that error should be resolved.

Comment: gah what an obvious error! (slap to forehead).  thanks!